# Device number linux module issue

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm developing character devices for a Linux kernel distro Poky 1.7 built with Yocto and installed on a Freescale imx6sx target board. They're simple modules, that are just used to read/write IO registers of the SoC.
Everything has worked well till I've load the modules after login, by simple calling in the target console

```
modprobe mydevice
```

Problems have begun since I've automatically load this modules at boot time. First time system startup after flashing my board, my custom modules are loaded and I can open them, do read/write operations...therefore they're working.
Restarting the system (switching it off and on or rebooting), modules are still loaded, but I'm unable to use them.

After some trials, what I've seen is that the problem is dynamic allocation of the device number they use, in particular function *alloc_chrdev_region( )* called in the *__init( )* function of the module.
In fact, really first time the system is switched on after has been flashed, the device file's device number in */dev* is up-to-date with the */sys/class/myclass/mydevice/dev* device number, while from the first reboot they doesn't match anymore. Briefly:

```
 First boot:    

 /dev/mydevice                         device number [Major, Minor] = 247,0
 /sys/class/myclass/mydevice/dev       device number [Major, Minor] = 247,0

 Second and later boots:

 /dev/mydevice                         device number [Major, Minor] = 247,0
 /sys/class/myclass/mydevice/dev       device number [Major, Minor] = 248,0
```

So, it seems like the device file is kept in memory instead of been updated at every boot.

Here is main code for *__init( )* and *__exit( )* functions:

```
static struct class *g_deviceClass;
static struct cdev g_characterDevice;
static dev_t g_deviceNumber;

static int __init npe_power_drv_init(void)
{
    int32_t result;

    if ( alloc_chrdev_region(&g_deviceNumber, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME) < 0 )
    {
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    cdev_init(&g_characterDevice, &npe_power_drv_ops);

    g_deviceClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);

    if( device_create(g_deviceClass, NULL, g_deviceNumber, NULL, DEVICE_NAME) == NULL )
    {
        class_destroy(g_deviceClass);
        unregister_chrdev_region(g_deviceNumber, 1);
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    result = cdev_add(&g_characterDevice, g_deviceNumber, 1);

    if( result < 0 )
    {
        device_destroy(g_deviceClass, g_deviceNumber);
            class_destroy(g_deviceClass);
        unregister_chrdev_region(g_deviceNumber, 1);
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    return 0;
}   

static void __exit npe_power_drv_exit(void)
{
    device_destroy(g_deviceClass, g_deviceNumber);
    class_destroy(g_deviceClass);
    cdev_del(&g_characterDevice);
    unregister_chrdev_region(g_deviceNumber, 1);
}

module_init(npe_power_drv_init);
module_exit(npe_power_drv_exit);
```

Using static device number allocation, *register_chrdev_region( )* everything works fine. Sure I can use this latter way to implement my code, but I would like to know why I've got this behaviour.

Many thanks for any help

Andrea

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code. Perhaps something is saving and restoring the _/dev_ entries? Also check _/proc/devices_ for comparison.

Comment: There should be no node under /dev for dynamic case. This is udev's business how and when to create a dev node.

Comment: Does your system use devtfmps ? You can check it by looking at the content of `/proc/mounts`. If yes, there should be no "persistence" in /dev and it should be repopulated at every boot.

Comment: @Longfield Yes, reading '/proc/mounts' I confirm that my stystem is using _devtmpfs_ .

Comment: @0andriy According to waht you're saying, problem resides in _udev_ rules or something related to it. In this case, it sounds like it doesn't "delete" LKM device node, am I right?

Comment: There is should **not** be node in the first place!

Comment: Since the modules are automatically loaded at boot time I think there should be node, because something like _modprobe_ is called at boot time

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "load this module at boot time" ? Is the driver built in the kernel ? Or is it loaded by some script ?

Comment: The driver is an out-of-tree module and it is loaded just after udev is launched, before the system enters run level 5. I don't know if there's a specific script who loads the module since I've specified this behaviour through the use of Yocto keyword KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD in my BitBake recipe.